# Move cells in UITableView

Tags: swift2

Is there any way to move cells programatically in UITableView? For example I have 3 cells located in the following order:

```
Cell 1
Cell 2
Cell 3
```

I perform something like this:

```
UITableView.GetCell(2).MoveToPosition(1);
```

And I get the following order:

```
Cell 2
Cell 1
Cell 3
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you call `tableView.reloadData()` and then return whatever cell you want in `cellForRowAtIndex`.